# Why won't my deployment group agent connect to the server?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm trying to provision a deployment group agent (vsts-agent-win-x64-2.170.1.zip) on a lab machine for an on-premises DevOps server.  The registration script successfully completes, the VstsAgentAService runs, and I can see the agent in the deployment group (the machine is present and all the Capabilities are visible) but it appears **Offline**.

Even though the script was clearly able to communicate with the server to provide the Capabilities, things break down when it's the agent's turn.

Event Viewer (VstsAgentAService):

```
2022-05-16 18:19:32Z: Agent connect error: An error occurred while sending the request.. Retrying until reconnected.
```

_diag log:

```
[2022-05-16 18:15:59Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Starting operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2022-05-16 18:15:59Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 1 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:15:59Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 1 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:15:59Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 1 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:10Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 2 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:10Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 2 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:10Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 2 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:23Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 3 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:23Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 3 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:24Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Attempt 3 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The operation will be retried[...]
[2022-05-16 18:16:40Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] Attempt 4 of GET request to https://[url] failed (WinHttp Error: ERROR_WINHTTP_SECURE_FAILURE). The maximum number of attempts has been reached.
[2022-05-16 18:16:40Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2022-05-16 18:16:40Z INFO AgentServer] Catch exception during connect. 4 attempt left.
[2022-05-16 18:16:40Z ERR  AgentServer] System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
 ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException (80072F8F, 12175): Error 12175 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'A security error occurred'.
```

This is when I run the registration script with authentication type: negotiate.  If I instead run the script using PAT, it fails right off the bat.

config.cmd:

```
Enter authentication type (press enter for PAT) >
Enter personal access token > ****************************************************
Error reported in diagnostic logs. Please examine the log for more details.
    - C:\dev\azagent\_diag\Agent_20220516-174740-utc.log
TF400813: Resource not available for anonymous access. Client authentication required.
```

_diag log:

```
[2022-05-16 17:55:48Z WARN VisualStudioServices] Basic issued token provider instance 52136803 requires an interactive prompt which is not allowed by the current settings
[2022-05-16 17:55:48Z ERR  VisualStudioServices] GET request to https://[url] is not authorized. Details: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://[url].
[2022-05-16 17:55:48Z INFO VisualStudioServices] Finished operation Location.GetConnectionData
[2022-05-16 17:55:48Z INFO LocationServer] Catch exception during connect. 4 attempt left.
[2022-05-16 17:55:48Z ERR  LocationServer] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssUnauthorizedException: VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://[url].
```

If I go to the URL with Chrome (and enter my credentials), it dumps a bunch of "authenticatedUser" information. Clearly the server is happy with my credentials.

Does anyone know what's going on? What am I missing to make the sever recognize the agent beyond the initial registration?